# Kubernetes node-exporter container is not working it shows this error message

Tags: docker, kubernetes, prometheus, grafana, prometheus-node-exporter

```text
Error: failed to start container "node-exporter": Error response from daemon: path /sys is mounted on /sys but it is not a shared or slave mount
```

shows that message here is the repository I took it from trying to make a node exporter to Grafana dashboard through Kubernetes pods followed this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1-tRiThpFrY&t=791s) and this [repo](https://github.com/marcel-dempers/docker-development-youtube-series/tree/master/monitoring/prometheus/kubernetes/1.18.4)

ERROR screenshot
[image]

Comment: Could you please try this solution?
https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/issues/467#issuecomment-957091174

Comment: should i run the command in the poweshell

Comment: after deploying the pods

Comment: Yes, after you have Prometheus installed and the node exporter giving error, then try this solution.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 5):

Well for me (Docker-Desktop in MacOS) this command saved my day:

```
kubectl patch ds monitoring-prometheus-node-exporter --type "json" -p '[{"op": "remove", "path" : "/spec/template/spec/containers/0/volumeMounts/2/mountPropagation"}]'
```

credit: [GitHub Issues](https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/issues/467#issuecomment-793682080)

Answer (score 1):

### What is the issue

---

This is not an issue of node exporter or helm chart or Kubernetes or docker but a limitation of docker desktop. Only people using Kubernetes on the docker desktop should be the ones facing the issue.

Take a look at the [values.yaml](https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/blob/main/charts/prometheus-node-exporter/values.yaml#L281) from prometheus-node-exporter

```yaml
# Mount the node's root file system (/) at /host/root in the container
hostRootFsMount:
  enabled: true
  # Defines how new mounts in existing mounts on the node or in the container
  # are propagated to the container or node, respectively. Possible values are
  # None, HostToContainer, and Bidirectional. If this field is omitted, then
  # None is used. More information on:
  # https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#mount-propagation
  mountPropagation: HostToContainer
```

It is using mount propagation. Now, take a look at the [docker documentation:](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/#configure-bind-propagation):

> Bind propagation defaults to rprivate for both bind mounts and volumes. It is only configurable for bind mounts, and *only on Linux host machines*. Bind propagation is an advanced topic and many users never need to configure it.

furthermore, and the most important one:
[image: Image containing Warning message stating that Mount propagations don't work with Docker Desktop from docker documentation]

### Okay but tell me how to solve it

---

You can turn off the hostRootFsMount, of course, by using the `kubectl patch` as suggested by Ali's answer, or you can use

```bash
helm install prom prometheus-community/kube-prometheus-stack -f node-exporter-workaround.yaml
OR
helm install prom prometheus-community/kube-prometheus-stack --set prometheus-node-exporter.hostRootFsMount.enabled=false
```

```
# node-exporter-workaround.yaml
prometheus-node-exporter:
  hostRootFsMount:
    enabled: false
```

I am using kube-prometheus-stack [chart](https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/blob/main/charts/kube-prometheus-stack/Chart.yaml#L46) in my case, and it contains the dependency of node exporter with the name `prometheus-node-exporter`, thus the first line of the yaml contains `prometheus-node-exporter`, and it can be different if the name of the dependency is different for the chart you are using.

```
dependencies:
  ...
  - name: prometheus-node-exporter
    version: "4.14.*"
    repository: https://prometheus-community.github.io/helm-charts
    condition: nodeExporter.enabled
```

If you are using the prometheus-node-exporter chart directly, then you can install it with `--set hostRootFsMount.enabled=false`

### BUT

---

Bear in mind that by disabling mount propagation node-exporter won't be able to collect all data needed for grafana dashboards and for alerts. -- [paulfantom](https://github.com/prometheus-operator/kube-prometheus/discussions/790#discussioncomment-964581) [maintainer]

So, what does this mean?
It means this is a workaround and not a solution. There are side effects to it. But on the bright side, this is a docker desktop issue. Prometheus should work fine on your production clusters. But if you are using docker desktop as your production env, then you need to reconsider some of your life choices. Have a nice day! :)

Answer (score 0):

This work for me (Docker-Dektop in MacOs m1)

```
# Mount the node's root file system (/) at /host/root in the container
hostRootFsMount:
  enabled: false
  # Defines how new mounts in existing mounts on the node or in the container
  # are propagated to the container or node, respectively. Possible values are
  # None, HostToContainer, and Bidirectional. If this field is omitted, then
  # None is used. More information on:
  # https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#mount-propagation
  mountPropagation: HostToContainer
```

[image]