# Connection refused on Prometheus metrics target deployed on Minikube with a custom SSL certificate

Tags: kubernetes, ssl, prometheus, kubernetes-helm, minikube

I am currently having issues trying to get Prometheus to scrape the metrics for my Minikube cluster. Prometheus is installed via the `kube-prometheus-stack`

```bash
kubectl create namespace monitoring && \
helm repo add prometheus-community https://prometheus-community.github.io/helm-charts && \
helm repo update && \
helm install -n monitoring prometheus-stack prometheus-community/kube-prometheus-stack
```

I am currently accessing Prometheus from an Ingress with a locally signed TLS certificate and it appears it's leading to conflicts as connection keeps getting refused by the cluster.

TLS is set up via Minikube ingress [add-on](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/tutorials/custom_cert_ingress/):

```bash
kubectl create secret -n kube-system tls mkcert-tls-secret --cert=cert.pem --key=key.pem
minikube addons configure ingress <<< "kube-system/mkcert-tls-secret" && \
minikube addons disable ingress && \
minikube addons enable ingress
```

It seems Prometheus can't get access to `http-metrics` as a target. I installed Prometheus via a helm chart:

```bash
kubectl create namespace monitoring && \
helm repo add prometheus-community https://prometheus-community.github.io/helm-charts && \
helm repo update && \
helm install -n monitoring prometheus-stack prometheus-community/kube-prometheus-stack
```

Here is my Prometheus configuration:

```yaml
global:
  scrape_interval: 30s
  scrape_timeout: 10s
  evaluation_interval: 30s
  external_labels:
    prometheus: monitoring/prometheus-stack-kube-prom-prometheus
    prometheus_replica: prometheus-prometheus-stack-kube-prom-prometheus-0
alerting:
  alert_relabel_configs:
  - separator: ;
    regex: prometheus_replica
    replacement: $1
    action: labeldrop
  alertmanagers:
  - follow_redirects: true
    enable_http2: true
    scheme: http
    path_prefix: /
    timeout: 10s
    api_version: v2
    relabel_configs:
    - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_service_name]
      separator: ;
      regex: prometheus-stack-kube-prom-alertmanager
      replacement: $1
      action: keep
    - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_endpoint_port_name]
      separator: ;
      regex: http-web
      replacement: $1
      action: keep
    kubernetes_sd_configs:
    - role: endpoints
      kubeconfig_file: ""
      follow_redirects: true
      enable_http2: true
      namespaces:
        own_namespace: false
        names:
        - monitoring
rule_files:
- /etc/prometheus/rules/prometheus-prometheus-stack-kube-prom-prometheus-rulefiles-0/*.yaml
scrape_configs:
- job_name: serviceMonitor/monitoring/prometheus-stack-kube-prom-kube-controller-manager/0
  honor_timestamps: true
  scrape_interval: 30s
  scrape_timeout: 10s
  metrics_path: /metrics
  scheme: https
  authorization:
    type: Bearer
    credentials_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token
  tls_config:
    ca_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt
    insecure_skip_verify: true
  follow_redirects: true
  enable_http2: true
  relabel_configs:
  - source_labels: [job]
    separator: ;
    regex: (.*)
    target_label: __tmp_prometheus_job_name
    replacement: $1
    action: replace
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_service_label_app, __meta_kubernetes_service_labelpresent_app]
    separator: ;
    regex: (kube-prometheus-stack-kube-controller-manager);true
    replacement: $1
    action: keep
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_service_label_release, __meta_kubernetes_service_labelpresent_release]
    separator: ;
    regex: (prometheus-stack);true
    replacement: $1
    action: keep
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_endpoint_port_name]
    separator: ;
    regex: http-metrics
    replacement: $1
    action: keep
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_endpoint_address_target_kind, __meta_kubernetes_endpoint_address_target_name]
    separator: ;
    regex: Node;(.*)
    target_label: node
    replacement: ${1}
    action: replace
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_endpoint_address_target_kind, __meta_kubernetes_endpoint_address_target_name]
    separator: ;
    regex: Pod;(.*)
    target_label: pod
    replacement: ${1}
    action: replace
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_namespace]
    separator: ;
    regex: (.*)
    target_label: namespace
    replacement: $1
    action: replace
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_service_name]
    separator: ;
    regex: (.*)
    target_label: service
    replacement: $1
    action: replace
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_name]
    separator: ;
    regex: (.*)
    target_label: pod
    replacement: $1
    action: replace
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_container_name]
    separator: ;
    regex: (.*)
    target_label: container
    replacement: $1
    action: replace
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_service_name]
    separator: ;
    regex: (.*)
    target_label: job
    replacement: ${1}
    action: replace
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_service_label_jobLabel]
    separator: ;
    regex: (.+)
    target_label: job
    replacement: ${1}
    action: replace
  - separator: ;
    regex: (.*)
    target_label: endpoint
    replacement: http-metrics
    action: replace
  - source_labels: [__address__]
    separator: ;
    regex: (.*)
    modulus: 1
    target_label: __tmp_hash
    replacement: $1
    action: hashmod
  - source_labels: [__tmp_hash]
    separator: ;
    regex: "0"
    replacement: $1
    action: keep
  kubernetes_sd_configs:
  - role: endpoints
    kubeconfig_file: ""
    follow_redirects: true
    enable_http2: true
    namespaces:
      own_namespace: false
      names:
      - kube-system
- job_name: serviceMonitor/monitoring/prometheus-stack-kube-prom-kube-etcd/0
  honor_timestamps: true
  scrape_interval: 30s
  scrape_timeout: 10s
  metrics_path: /metrics
  scheme: http
  authorization:
    type: Bearer
    credentials_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token
  follow_redirects: true
  enable_http2: true
  relabel_configs:
  - source_labels: [job]
    separator: ;
    regex: (.*)
    target_label: __tmp_prometheus_job_name
    replacement: $1
    action: replace
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_service_label_app, __meta_kubernetes_service_labelpresent_app]
    separator: ;
    regex: (kube-prometheus-stack-kube-etcd);true
    replacement: $1
    action: keep
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_service_label_release, __meta_kubernetes_service_labelpresent_release]
    separator: ;
    regex: (prometheus-stack);true
    replacement: $1
    action: keep
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_endpoint_port_name]
    separator: ;
    regex: http-metrics
    replacement: $1
    action: keep
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_endpoint_address_target_kind, __meta_kubernetes_endpoint_address_target_name]
    separator: ;
    regex: Node;(.*)
    target_label: node
    replacement: ${1}
    action: replace
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_endpoint_address_target_kind, __meta_kubernetes_endpoint_address_target_name]
    separator: ;
    regex: Pod;(.*)
    target_label: pod
    replacement: ${1}
    action: replace
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_namespace]
    separator: ;
    regex: (.*)
    target_label: namespace
    replacement: $1
    action: replace
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_service_name]
    separator: ;
    regex: (.*)
    target_label: service
    replacement: $1
    action: replace
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_name]
    separator: ;
    regex: (.*)
    target_label: pod
    replacement: $1
    action: replace
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_container_name]
    separator: ;
    regex: (.*)
    target_label: container
    replacement: $1
    action: replace
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_service_name]
    separator: ;
    regex: (.*)
    target_label: job
    replacement: ${1}
    action: replace
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_service_label_jobLabel]
    separator: ;
    regex: (.+)
    target_label: job
    replacement: ${1}
    action: replace
  - separator: ;
    regex: (.*)
    target_label: endpoint
    replacement: http-metrics
    action: replace
  - source_labels: [__address__]
    separator: ;
    regex: (.*)
    modulus: 1
    target_label: __tmp_hash
    replacement: $1
    action: hashmod
  - source_labels: [__tmp_hash]
    separator: ;
    regex: "0"
    replacement: $1
    action: keep
  kubernetes_sd_configs:
  - role: endpoints
    kubeconfig_file: ""
    follow_redirects: true
    enable_http2: true
    namespaces:
      own_namespace: false
      names:
      - kube-system
```

I am also currently accessing (works just fine) the Prometheus instance outside of the cluster with an Ingress using the TLS certificate:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: prometheusdashboard-ingress
  namespace: monitoring
  labels:
    name: prometheusdashboard-ingress
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - prometheus.demo
    secretName: mkcert-tls-secret
  rules:
  - host: prometheus.demo
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: "/"
        backend:
          service:
            name: prometheus-stack-kube-prom-prometheus
            port:
              number: 9090
```

Here's the output in the target page of Prometheus:

[image: Prometheus targets]

What do I get the stack access to this TLS certificate which I assume is the main issue here?

Comment: I don't believe the problem is with the certificates. I think the problem is that there is no open port at the provided endpoints for Prometheus to scrape.

Comment: I haven't touched any port. How do I even potentially verify this?

Comment: log into your pods and check for open ports. `kubectl exec -ti <podname> bash` and then `ss -ltn | grep <portnum>`

Comment: @zer0 none of the pods which could be exec into (only `etcd-minikube` worked) had ss installed and I can't tell which linux OS is running in it since apt doesn't work either

Comment: Yeah seem not prometheus issue, you can take a look using cat /proc/$PID/net/tcp, the pid for container process can get from ps aux or usually 1 for main process in a container

Answer (score 2):

## Solution to the problem

After some thorough analysis of my various kubernetes clusters, I have found out the following errors exist:

#### Docker Desktop Environment throws this:

`Warning  Failed     6s (x3 over 30s)   kubelet            Error: failed to start container "node-exporter": Error response from daemon: path / is mounted on / but it is not a shared or slave mount`

The [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70556984/kubernetes-node-exporter-container-is-not-working-it-shows-this-error-message) tries solving it but it didn't work out for me.

#### Minikube Environment

The same error was replicated there too, I opened the web UI for minikube and found that these services were related to these ports
[image: Web UI]

Through this image, we can understand that these services are relevant to these ports. You can try port-forwarding them but even that doesn't help much.

The only way I can see this working is to apply the configuration through [prometheus chart](https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/prometheus).

Comment: the url for the chart is broken?

Comment: Let me get it, https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/kube-prometheus-stack

Answer (score 2):

## After some more analysis

You can use the `kubernetes-dashboard` namespace using the following commmand to access the metrics.

After some debugging, these are the following images used by MiniKube:

- [kubernetesui/metrics-scraper](https://hub.docker.com/r/kubernetesui/metrics-scraper)
- [kubernetesui/dashboard:v2.3.1](https://hub.docker.com/r/kubernetesui/dashboard)
- [K8S Provisioner](https://console.cloud.google.com/gcr/images/k8s-minikube/GLOBAL/storage-provisioner@sha256:18eb69d1418e854ad5a19e399310e52808a8321e4c441c1dddad8977a0d7a944?tag=v5)

### Okay now, what do I do with the Namespace?

You can access the namespace and check out the services.

`kubectl get svc`

```
NAME                        TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE
dashboard-metrics-scraper   ClusterIP   10.98.229.151   <none>        8000/TCP   3m55s
kubernetes-dashboard        ClusterIP   10.107.41.221   <none>        80/TCP     3m55s
```

Using the kubernetes-dashboard service, you can access metrics from the services. It goes to `localhost:9090/metrics` where you can get some more metrics like this:

[image]

#### EDIT

*You can configure prometheus to access these metrics.*

#### EDIT II

I am not a prometheus expert but I am of a certain opinion that the above mentioned config file isn't best suited for mining metrics. You should consider using a custom config file.

Comment: This should be working with prometheus even if it fails with kube-prometheus-stack

Comment: https://github.com/prometheus-operator/kube-prometheus/issues/913 will also help you for the deployment